# SQL Server CE - Select random rows

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce, sql-server-ce-3.5

How do you select a random rows from a table?

For example, if there are 1000 rows in a table matching the criteria that I want, I want to select just 20 random ones.

Like TOP, but random.

Thanks, and this is for SQL Server CE 3.5!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
 SELECT TOP(20) * FROM myTable ORDER BY NEWID()
```

Comment: @Mitch - that's weird, unfortunately I don't have 4.0 to try it on at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

How about `SELECT * FROM tbl_name ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,20;` 
However if your db is with million rows Both newid() and rand() would perform slow.
There is a faster solution .[Read this](http://explainextended.com/2009/03/01/selecting-random-rows/)

Comment: If the query I end up making is too slow I will have to take a look at that. Thanks for posting.

Comment: RAND() is for MySQL, the question is about SQL SERVER CE.